# Merge documentation tags iOS, ios10, ios9, ios8 and ios7

Tags: support, documentation, tag-alias-request

Yes. You read correctly. There are FIVE tags about iOS in documentation. I don't know how we could find 5 people to commit on [ios10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios10)&[ios9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios9) and how someone could propose [ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios8) and [ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios7).

In my opinion, we should merge these tags. There is the possibility of using [inline versions](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#inline-versions) if something differs from version to version.

Comment: There are a lot of tags with this problem. Another example would be `asp.net-mvc`, `asp.net-mvc-4` and `asp.net-mvc-5`.

Comment: @TotZam I think is better to 'ask' a different [tag-alias-request] for those.

Comment: @Athafoud Done. I created a separate tag alias request for the asp.net tags [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334170/merge-documentation-tags-asp-net-mvc-4-and-asp-net-mcv-5-with-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Possible others that should being aliased: [ios] or [ios7] or [ios5] or [ios4] or [ios8] or [ios6] or [ios9] or [ios-ui-automation] or [ios7.1] or [ios-provisioning] or [ios-app-extension] or [ios10] or [ios-autolayout] or [ios8.1] or [ios-frameworks] or [ios-4.2] or [ios5.1] or [ios-universal-app]