# Merge Documentation Tags [asp.net-mvc-4] and [asp.net-mcv-5] with [asp.net-mvc]

Tags: support, documentation, tag-alias-request

As suggested in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334159/merge-documentation-tags-ios-ios9-ios8-and-ios7?noredirect=1#comment393194_334159), I am creating a separate tag alias request to merge the [asp.net-mvc-4](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc-4/topics) and [asp.net-mvc-5](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc-5/topics) Documentation tags with the main [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-mvc/topics) tag.

Both the 4 and 5 versions have been around for a bit and still do not have an of their own topics. If there is something that is specific to one of these MVC flavors, inline versioning will most probably always suffice.

Comment: Are these two tags the only two?

Comment: There is a rather large difference between 4 and 5. They require different Visual Studio versions, Identity is in full swing by 5, Web API is more integrated in 5, the bundling is semi forced, the set of includes for references in individual view folders (local web.config) is different, default serialization changed from jss to json.net, etc. 5 Was a decently large departure from the style of 3 and 4, similar to how 3 was a decent departure from 1 and 2. If we are to keep topics and examples small, then we need more granular tags like this.

Comment: @travisj that is precisely what the versioning syntax is for.

Comment: @RubberDuck - Perhaps. Doesn't that just create an excessive amount of topics though?

Comment: No @TravisJ, it actually reduces the number of examples per topic. If you'd do the same thing in two different ways, the example contains one for each version(s).

Comment: @RubberDuck - I suppose that is the way it was designed. There is a precedence for it with css3 -> css as well apparently, and in [this recent post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331694/1026459) they plan to do it to c++. Alright, sounds fine to me if that is the outlook.